# How to correctly pivot a dataframe so the values of the first column are my new columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file with some random census data, in essence multiple lines of the following:

```
age=senior workclass=Self-emp-not-inc education=Bachelors edu_num=13 marital=Divorced occupation=Craft-repair relationship=Not-in-family race=White sex=Male gain=high loss=none hours=half-time country=United-States salary>50K
```

I want to transform this into a csv that looks like this:

```
senior Self-emp-not-inc Bachelors ... >50K
```

I created the following script that I was hoping would do what I want:

```
 for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    temp_df = df.loc[i].str.split(" ", expand=True)
    temp_df = temp_df[0].str.split("=", expand=True)    

    temp_df.columns = ['column_names', 'column_values']
    temp_df = temp_df.reset_index(drop=True)

    temp_df = temp_df.pivot(index=temp_df.index, columns='column_names', values='column_values')
```

The last line though is throwing an error, specifically:

```
KeyError: 0
```

How can I either fix my `pivot` or if this is not correct, what would be a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Please provide a data frame constructor. It should easily be adapted from `your_df.to_dict()`.

Comment: You shouldn't do this in groups, but rather, in the whole. The pivot command asks what your index is, which is the index in the resulting data frame. In this instance, it would probably be some unique identifier for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe does indeed look like this.

```
print(df)
               0                           1                    2   ...               11                     12          13
0  age=senior  workclass=Self-emp-not-inc  education=Bachelors  ...  hours=half-time  country=United-States  salary>50K
```

you could `stack`, `split` and `unstack` to get the columns you need.

```
df1 = df.stack()\
.str.split('=|>|<=|<|>=',expand=True)\
.reset_index(1,drop=True)\
.set_index(0,append=True)\
.unstack(1)
```

---

```
print(df1)
0     age        country edu_num  education  gain  ...   race   relationship salary   sex         workclass
0  senior  United-States      13  Bachelors  high  ...  White  Not-in-family    50K  Male  Self-emp-not-inc
```

Comment: There is a slight issue with the salary field, since it can be <=50, >50 and so on. But that's just specific to this dataset and I should be able to fix. Otherwise this seems like the most convenient method.

Comment: pretty simple @dearn44 see edit. `str.split` accepts regex patterns, so the world is your oyster :) thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just create a function that handles the split, returning a dictionary of column_name:column_value pairs, and then create a dataframe from that a list of those dictionaries.

```
def gen_dic_from_val(x):
    l = [re.split('=|>|<',v) for v in x.split(' ')]
    return {k[0]:k[1] for k in l}

pd.DataFrame(df.val.apply(lambda x: gen_dic_from_val(x)).to_list())
```

(This assumes `df` is a `pd.DataFrame` holding your long string values in a column named `val`)

Answer (score 0):

Given a data frame with an ID column:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0], 's': 'age=senior workclass=Self-emp-not-inc education=Bachelors edu_num=13 marital=Divorced occupation=Craft-repair relationship=Not-in-family race=White sex=Male gain=high loss=none hours=half-time country=United-States salary>50K'})
```

Create a new data frame from the list version of the data:

```
>>> df['sl'] = df['s'].str.split(' ', expand=False)
>>> df1 = df.explode('sl')
   id  ...                          sl
0   0  ...                  age=senior
0   0  ...  workclass=Self-emp-not-inc
0   0  ...         education=Bachelors
0   0  ...                  edu_num=13
0   0  ...            marital=Divorced
0   0  ...     occupation=Craft-repair
0   0  ...  relationship=Not-in-family
0   0  ...                  race=White
0   0  ...                    sex=Male
0   0  ...                   gain=high
0   0  ...                   loss=none
0   0  ...             hours=half-time
0   0  ...       country=United-States
0   0  ...                  salary>50K

[14 rows x 3 columns]
```

Create your names and values from your second split.

```
>>> df1[['n', 'v']] = df1['sl'].str.split('=', expand=True)
>>> df1[['id', 'n', 'v']]
   id             n                 v
0   0           age            senior
0   0     workclass  Self-emp-not-inc
0   0     education         Bachelors
0   0       edu_num                13
0   0       marital          Divorced
0   0    occupation      Craft-repair
0   0  relationship     Not-in-family
0   0          race             White
0   0           sex              Male
0   0          gain              high
0   0          loss              none
0   0         hours         half-time
0   0       country     United-States
0   0    salary>50K              None
```

Then just pivot into place.

```
>>> df1.pivot(index='id', columns='n', values='v')
n      age        country edu_num  ... salary>50K   sex         workclass
id                                 ...                                   
0   senior  United-States      13  ...       None  Male  Self-emp-not-inc
```

Because each observation (the `index` in `df.pivot`) is uniquely identified, this works over the entire data frame as a whole. If you don't have an `id` column already, create one by `df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'id'})` at the very start.